# Sort table in PHP by the value of the last column, which is a calculated variable

Tags: php, sorting, variables, html-table

This is the code that I have:

---

```
<?

$i=0;

foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{

?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=number_format($value[budget],0)?></td>
        <td><?=number_format($value[htd],0)?></td>
        <td><?=number_format($value[etc],0)?></td>
        <td><?

        $per=number_format(($value[htd]+$value[etc])/$value[budget],2);

        echo $per;

        ?></td>
    </tr>
<?$i++;}?>
```

---

So, $per is a calculated value, and I would like to sort my table by that number. Can I get some help doing this?

Comment: This is not related to what you're asking, but you need to quote your array keys. It should be `$value['budget']`, etc.

Comment: Where is this data coming from?  A database table?  That's the proper place to do the sorting..  and calculations.

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic.

Comment: Yes @mickmackusa, it comes from a Database

Comment: So, if I wanted to do the columns sortable, should I use the same method??

Comment: If you want to receive a high quality answer that uses best practices, post an sql_ fiddle link that provides your table structure, table data, and your query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the data once you have it, so:

```
//add what you want first
foreach($data as $key => $value){
  $data[$key]['per'] = ($value['htd'] + $value['etc']) / $value['budget'];
}

//then sort
usort($data, function($a, $b){
  return $a['per'] == $b['per'] ? 0 : ($a['per'] > $b['per'] ? 1 : -1 );
});

//then display the data
foreach($data as $key => $value){
?>
  <tr>
    <td><? echo number_format($value['budget'],0); ?></td>
    <td><? echo number_format($value['htd'],0); ?></td>
    <td><? echo number_format($value['etc'],0); ?></td>
    <td><? echo number_format($value['per'],2); ?></td>
  </tr>
<?
}
```

Comment: @Don'tPanic You are right. I fixed it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: No problem :) One more note, if one can use PHP 7, the combined comparison operator makes it much neater. (`$a['per'] <=> $b['per']`)

Answer (score -1):

Before output table you need to sort the $data array using some of [PHP sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). Look at [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function. It can help you.